# Unity with google cardboard, trying to control the camera with head tracking and dragging a finger

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm trying to make a unity app, that is like the 360 youtube viewer, but just for images.
So I'm trying to be able to rotate the camera by dragging my finger, and by rotating the device.

The image is rendered on a skymap and the camera is at (0,0,0).

I'm using the cardboard sdk for the head rotation, and it works great alone.
I also have a smooth look script for the camera that also works great alone.
But when i try to control the camera with both methods stuff gets weird: sometimes the head rotation or the dragging is opposite on the y axis, and other weird like that.

(The hierarchy is Cardboard main-> Cardboard head -> empty gameobject with the dragging script -> cardboard camera)
I have tried other ways, but nothing seems to work well.

How can I implement both ways of controlling the camera, like it is in the panoramic youtube player?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the empty game object with the script at the top of the hierarchy, with the Cardboard Main as a child? I made a game that does the same thing and I think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex, but this still doesn't work for me, i guess my problem is with the dragging script I'm using. What script did you use?
Thank you very much!